# Chi squre test of two groups of data in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of two groups of variables upon 4 variables like the following. How can I see the chi-square correlation in R in these two groups?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av5ii.png)

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `chisq.test()`